# How to include `search_type=count` in a query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a Python script that runs many ElasticSearch aggregations, e.g.:

```
client = Elasticsearch(...)
q =  {"aggs": {"my_name":{"terms": "field", "fieldname"}}}
res = client.search(index = "indexname*", doc_type = "doc_type", body = q)
```

But this returns the search query (match everything I think) `res["hits"]` and the aggregation results `res["aggregations"]`.

What I want to run is the Python equivalent of the following

```
GET /index*/doc_type/_search?search_type=count

{"aggs": {"my_name":{"terms": "field", "fieldname"}}}
```

How do I make sure to include the `?search_type=count` when using Python Elasticsearch?

I'd like to know this in general, but the current reason I'm looking into this is I occasionally get errors caused by timeouts or data size when running the queries. My suspicion is that if I can only ask for the counting then I'll avoid these.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The general consensus is to not use `search_type=count` anymore as it's [been deprecated in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_count_literal_deprecated). Instead you should simply use `size: 0`.

```
res = client.search(index = "indexname*", doc_type = "doc_type", body = q, size=0)
                                                                             ^
                                                                             |
                                                                         add this
```

Comment: This worked! I don't quite understand the documentation to which you linked. Is there a `query_then_fetch` example?

Comment: `query_then_fetch` is the default search type, i.e. no need to specify it. The link I shared is just a list of breaking changes in ES 2.0, which means that as soon as you upgrade to 2.0, it's advised to use `size: 0` instead

Comment: Ran across the documentation for this and thought I'd provide the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: The link in the answer doesn't work anymore. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_21_search_changes.html instead

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) is the documentation for search

Try this

```
res = client.search(index = "indexname*", doc_type = "doc_type", body = q, search_type='count')
```

Look at the answer of @Val if you are using ES `2.x`

Comment: Sure, just make sure to add a big TODO just above that line to use `size` instead once you upgrade to 2.0.

Comment: Thanks @Val, I seriously need to look into 2.0 changes

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Lots of new stuff, indeed, definitely worth their weight in gold.